# how to make matplotlib text (xlabel, ticks etc..) saved as text and not as path (when saving image as pdf)

Tags: python, matplotlib, postscript

How can I save a matplotlib figure with text as a postscript image and that the text will be saved as text.
Currently when I save the image as postscript all the text in the image ( xlabel, ylabel etc.. ) is saved as path and not as text..
Is it possible to save it as text?

EDIT

If I use the following code ( use latex)

```
matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
```

and save the image as postscript the text is saved as text.. But I do not want to use latex.. Is it possible without latex?

Thanks

Comment: Due to the fact, that matplotlib allows to have besides some font-related formatting features also **rather complicated typographical content** in the xlabel-instance ( bear in mind using LaTeX-constructs as an illustrative example ), the PostScript-generator quite reasonably escapes into typesetting a set of paths, rather than reverse-engineering the xlabel-content and use a more straightforward text ( with some additional measures for preserving the typesetting context of the xlabel-formatting ).

Comment: @user3666197 I am not sure it is ture beacuse when I use matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True and save the image as postscript that image is saved with text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to make matplotlib save text as font and not path:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

Read more here: 
http://physicalmodelingwithpython.blogspot.com/2015/06/making-plots-for-publication.html